# Regex of XML with multiple tags

Tags: regex, xml

I'm trying to find all text that is not within the XML markup:

```
<transcript>
  <text start="9.75" dur="5.94">welcome to about my property here you
can learn more about how your property</text>
  <text start="15.69" dur="4.71">was assessed see the information impact
has on file and compare your property to</text>
  <text start="20.4" dur="1.3">others in your neighborhood</text>
  <text start="21.7" dur="5.32">interested in learning about market
trends in your municipality no problem</text>
  <text start="105.79" dur="6.23">I have all of this and more about life property
. see your property assessment know more</text>
  <text start="112.02" dur="0.11">about</text>
</transcript>
```

I am using the following regex pattern, but obviously it is not correct because it grabs all of the text between the opening and closing `<transcript>` tags:

```
<transcript>[\s\S]*?<\/transcript>
```

How can modify this regex pattern to select only the text that is not within any of the markup tags?

Comment: Don't parse XML with regex. Just don't. Use a proper XML parser.

Comment: Thanks @Biffen, could you suggest a good one?

Comment: @DanielAttard, what language are you using?

Comment: Unless your xml is always of the form, `<transcript><text start="#.##" dur="#.##"></text></transcript>`, you're not going to have much success using regex

Comment: Everything from `<transcript>..</transcript>` are "within XML markup", so there is no text at all *not* in XML. Do you possibly mean "not tagged with `<text>`"?

Comment: Thanks all.  I am using the JavaScript RegExp standard.

Comment: @RadLexus Yes, you are correct.  My bad, still learning...

Comment: @DanielAttard See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Parsing_and_serializing_XML

Comment: From the looks of this, I will look into using an XML parser.

Comment: This could be done with a basic XSLT transform, using a common XML parser such as msxml or Saxon.

Comment: I guess this is what you want `/\/\w+>([^<]+)</g`

Comment: @Redu: No, it most certainly is not.  **Don't parse XML with regex.**  An XML parser is what he wants.

Comment: @ kjhughes I think regexp is perfect for this very easy job. Plus he has already indicated what he is asking for.

Answer (score 1):

Use XSLT. XSLT is a language specifically designed to convert XML into another output format (back to valid XML again, or something else such as (X)HTML, plain text, or any other format – but preferably, based on plain text).

In this case the smallest XSLT necessary is just this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="2.0" >
<xsl:output method="text" indent="no" />

<xsl:template match="text">
    <!-- do NOTHING here! -->
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This works because the default for processing a single XML tag is to recursively apply template matches to its containing tags, and plain text will always be copied. The only tag inside your `<template>` is `<text>`, and you process it by doing 'nothing' – i.e., by *not* copying its contents to the output. The line inside that template is just a comment.

All other "nodes", in XML terminology, are those without a surrounding tag and so *are* copied to the output.

Alternatively, if you have more types of tags than just `<text>` elements and you want to skip all of them, apply templates to `/` and `transcript` to process each and apply another to `*` (which will select all remaining tags not specified elsewhere) to *not* process them:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="2.0" >
<xsl:output method="text" indent="no" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="transcript">
    <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <!-- do NOTHING here! -->
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Again, the plain untagged text will fall through and not get processed, so their contents will be copied to output.

Both XSLT stylesheets will output only `I ha`, the only part in your sample text that is not surrounded by tags.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to find

```
welcome to about my property here you can learn more about how your property
```

from

```
<text start="9.75" dur="5.94">welcome to about my property here you can learn more about how your property</text>
```

??

Than it will work.

```
(?<=>).+?(?=<)
```